# Prove a cube graph has no even walks?

Tags: graph-theory

The following question was in my exam, and I didn't even have any idea on how to start, so I'm quite curious to see a proof.

I was given a cube graph (the one on the left):

[cube http://www.math.ubc.ca/~solymosi/2007/443/index_files/image001.gif](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~solymosi/2007/443/index_files/image001.gif)

The question was as follows:

We were to pick two vertexes on the diagonal, and prove that there were no walks of even length. (By on the diagonal I mean e.g. the bottom front left to the top back right).

I had a look at the total number of degrees (24) and edges (8) but since these were all even I couldn't see why this would cause an odd walk.

This is a first year introductory course so I would appreciate as simple proof 
as possible, I am wondering if it may be covered by induction or possibly group theory (these are two of the things we covered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint: Color the vertices red  and blue  in a certain systematic way.

**Update** after your first comment: So you found the intended coloring and noted its essential feature.

Next hint: Start at a red vertex. What is the color of the vertex you are after an even number of steps?

**Update** after your second comment: Since there are two colors, and every step changes the color of the visited vertex, it is **obvious** that after an even number of steps you are at a  vertex of the same color as the starting vertex. A "formal proof" of this fact decreases its credibility, unless this is an exercise in writing up "formal proofs".

Comment: I am still really not sure what to do, or what kind of proof this even is. I can see that they alternate (i.e. you can colour them so any two adjacent vertices are different colours), but I have no idea how to articulate it into a proof.

Comment: They are all at the same colour after an even number of steps. But I don't know how I can 'prove' this either.

Comment: @Inazuma: If you can colour all the vertices so any two adjacent vertices are different colours (i.e. each step changes colour), and if diagonally opposite vertices have different colours, this tells you about the parity of path lengths between diagonally opposite vertices

Comment: Hmmm, I am getting a better idea now. I am not really sure whether this was meant to be a formal proof or not, but it did say 'Prove that...', but I am sure that I was just thrown off in the midst of exam adrenaline. Thank you for your help & @Henry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could redraw the cube graph as a bipartite graph consisting of 4 vertices on the left side and 4 vertices on the right side.  Observe that any walk from a left vertex to a right vertex must have odd length.